# Cannot drag a date from Notepad++ into a bootstrap datepicker control

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

`MVC Visual Studio 2015`, `ASP.NET 2013`
`bootstrap 3.3.7`, `jquery 2.2.4`
`IE 11` or `Chrome 79.0.3945.130`

When a drag the following text 2010-01-01 from Notepad++ into a datepicker (`class="datetimepicker input-group date"`), there is a forbidden black circle icon which denies the drop, As picture shown in below :

[![Trying to drop text][1]][1]

But was allowed a few days ago. How is this controlled, changed ?

Update: just noticed it has nothing to do with bootstrap, the black circle icon is showed on the whole page, not just the date picker.

Comment: Can you post more information, Your View and other related stuff

Answer (score 0):

Solution: start IE or Chrome in non-admin mode. In admin mode droping text into an input field is denied (black circle icon with a bar).

I was using a script to kill and restart IE for testing my app. I configured the windows shortcut to the script as "run as admin".Then I became unable do drag a test date into a field on the test page.